# Error 1136 in mysql

Tags: mysql

i keep getting the error 1136 in mysql, i need help, what's wrong with this code?

```
CREATE table Artist (
ArtistID INT,Salary varchar (20),Contract_End_Date date,Trackname varchar (20),
Artistname varchar (15),
Fname varchar (20), 
Lname varchar (20), 
Birthday date ,
PRIMARY KEY(ArtistID),
FOREIGN KEY (Salary) REFERENCES Contract(Salary),
FOREIGN KEY (Contract_End_Date) REFERENCES Contract(Contract_End_Date),
FOREIGN KEY (Trackname) REFERENCES Track(Trackname));


INSERT INTO Artist(ArtistID, Artistname, Fname, Lname, Birthday, Salary, Contract_End_Date, Trackname) VALUES (
'1','JM','John','Mcfierceson','1978-05-20','$100000','2017-05-08','Cries by the Ocean',
'2','Ray','Ray','Grueson','1990-07-10','$500000','2017-09-12','Jumping Jacks',
'3','Shiin','Charlie','Shiin','1989-02-12','$700000','2020-12-17','I can feel my head', 
'4','King','Bobby','Naval','1978-09-24','$7878787','2014-10-11','Rain',
'5','Yellowman','Chris, Yellow','1984-11-11','$8000000','2014-09-08','Falling',
'6','Sting','Karl','Shakur','1967-10-06','$5600000','2014-05-15','X',
'7','Kboy','Kendrick','Maine','1990-12-25','$8099999','2021-09-12','Trick');

CREATE table Contract (
Contractcode varchar (20), Artistname varchar(15),
Contract_start_Date date,
Contract_End_Date date,
Salary varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY(Contractcode),
FOREIGN KEY (Artistname) REFERENCES Artist(Artistname));

INSERT INTO Contract VALUES (
'1004JM', 'JM', '2011-05-08', '2017-05-08', '$100000 ', 
'2424RG', 'Ray', '2013-09-12', '2017-09-12', '$500000', 
'3446SC', 'Shiin', '2010-12-17', '2020-12-17', '$700000',  
'9999BN', 'King', '1990-10-11', '2014-10-11', '$7878787', 
'2546CY', 'Yellowman', '2000-09-08', '2014-09-08', '$8000000', 
'4446KS', 'Sting', '1980-05-15', '2014-05-15', '$5600000', 
'5454KM', 'Kboy', '2010-09-12', '2021-09-12', '$8099999');

CREATE table Track (
Trackname varchar (20),
Artistname varchar (15),
Tracktype  varchar (20),
Tracklength int ,
PRIMARY KEY(Trackname),
FOREIGN KEY (Artistname) REFERENCES Artist(Artistname));

INSERT INTO Track VALUES (
'Cries by the Ocean', 'Jumping Jacks', 'I can feel my head', 'Rain', 'Falling', 'X', 'Trick', 
'JM', 'Ray', 'Shiin', 'King', 'Yellowman', 'Sting', 'Kboy',
'Rock', 'Rock', 'Indie', 'RnB', 'Rock', 'Rock', 'Rock',
'4', '5', '3', '3', '5', '5', '5');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mysql Error 1136](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_wrong_value_count_on_row) means `Column count doesn't match value count`.

You seem to be inserting multiple rows with a single insert statement.

Each row of data should be in its own set of parenthesis. And each set of parenthesis should be separated by a comma. Something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO artist
  (artistid, artistname, fname, lname, birthday, salary, contract_end_date, trackname)
VALUES
  ('1', 'JM', 'John', 'Mcfierceson', '1978-05-20', '$100000', '2017-05-08', 'Cries by the Ocean'),
  ('2', 'Ray', 'Ray', 'Grueson', '1990-07-10', '$500000', '2017-09-12', 'Jumping Jacks'),
  ('3', 'Shiin', 'Charlie', 'Shiin', '1989-02-12', '$700000', '2020-12-17', 'I can feel my head'),
  ('4', 'King', 'Bobby', 'Naval', '1978-09-24', '$7878787', '2014-10-11', 'Rain'),
  ('5', 'Yellowman', 'Chris, Yellow', '1984-11-11', '$8000000', '2014-09-08', 'Falling'),
  ('6', 'Sting', 'Karl', 'Shakur', '1967-10-06', '$5600000', '2014-05-15', 'X'),
  ('7', 'Kboy', 'Kendrick', 'Maine', '1990-12-25', '$8099999', '2021-09-12', 'Trick');
```

[INSERT Syntax (Documentation)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plug more data than you have fields for.  Try this:

```
CREATE table Track ( Trackname varchar (20), 
                      Artistname varchar (15),
                      Tracktype varchar (20),
                      Tracklength int ,
                      PRIMARY KEY(Trackname), 
                      FOREIGN KEY (Artistname) 
                      REFERENCES Artist(Artistname));

INSERT INTO Track VALUES ( 'Cries by the Ocean', 'JM', 'Rock', '4'), 
                         ('Jumping Jacks', 'Ray', 'Rock', '5');
```

Enclose each row in a set of (), one row of data at a time.